# Bold font style for custom font in iOS application

Tags: ios, fonts

I have a custom font and it doesn't include bold face. I have no problem using it in web and Android since they use faux bold but, I don't know how can I make it bold in iOS.
I want to know if there is a way to make faux bold in iOS or any tool to create a bold font face from normal one using techniques that browsers use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `NSAttributedString` to stroke text and make them bold.

Try this code below:

```
  NSString *string = @"Hello World";
  NSMutableAttributedString *attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string];
  NSDictionary *attributes = @{
                       NSStrokeWidthAttributeName: @-5.0, //value for making bold, higher negative number bolder text
                       NSStrokeColorAttributeName:[UIColor blackColor],
                       NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor blackColor],
                       NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Your font name" size:20]
                            };
  [attrString addAttributes:attributes range:NSMakeRange(0, string.length)];
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did this but it just gives me the outline and it's empty inside.